# How to solve "Collection query aborted after accumulating over 5000 elements"?

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, sentinel-1, sampling, radar

I am trying to sample image and to get scatter plot of its' two bands- NDVI and db from senttinel 1.
For some reason, probably because of the size of the shapefile, I get the error:

> Error generating chart: Collection query aborted after accumulating
>   over 5000 elements.
>
> Collection query aborted after accumulating over 5000 elements

That's happens after I try to sample my image using this:

```
// Generate a sample of points within the region
var sample = pairedImage.sampleRegions(geometry, null,3);
```

I have playes with the last number in the funnction , I started with 50 but then went down to 30,10,5 ,1 and 3, but non of them worked and in all I have gotten the same error. is it possible that it happens because of the size of the image and there is nothing I can do?

Here is a link to my code:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/f967f358a45cc1c40ccc6d0373066270

My end goal: to be able to sample this image and create the chart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The collection you pass to `ui.Chart.feature.byFeature()` cannot contain more than 5000 features. In your case, your `sample` collection contains way more than 5000.

```
pairedImage.sampleRegions(geometry, null,3);
```

This samples your image at a scale of 3 meters. Since your image comes from Sentinel 2, it’s pointless to sampling at a scale smaller than 10 meters. Sampling your geometry at 10 meters gives you more than 600,000 features. That leaves you with two options: Sample at a larger scale or sample a smaller area. The below script samples at 100 meters:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/ce8aa2625c3bdf29e583364a19994dc4